# Binary controller transfer function

Tags: control-theory

I have a simple controller that turns off when my variable is over the setpoint and on when it's below. Is there any transfer function for modelling this?

Comment: With transfer function you are referring to linear time invariant systems? If so then no, since the threshold on/off is nonlinear.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Yes, you are right.